# Lighthouse: difference between results

Tags: performance, lighthouse

I'm optimizing a webpage using Lighthouse to monitor performance. I found consistent differences between the results I get running the audit in the Chrome extension and from the Developers Tab.

As an average I get the Largest Contentful Paint:

- Developers Tab (with no throttling): 2 - 2.5 secs
- Chrome extension: 5.5 - 7 secs

That LCP is an image and measuring it visualy I'm much nearer to the 2,5 secs.

Any clues on which measure should I rely on?

Thanks in advance!